# MySQL - add data into 2 tables and 1 has foreign key

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I'm a totally MySQL newcomer. Sr if my question is quite obvious. I got 2 tables

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_addresses(
  PK_ADDRESS_ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  house_number int NOT NULL,
  street varchar(35),
  district varchar(35),
  city varchar(35),
  postcode varchar(8),
  PRIMARY KEY (PK_ADDRESS_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE tbl_people(
  PK_PERSON_ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  title varchar(6) NOT NULL, # Master / Mister therefor 6 is max
  forename varchar(35) NOT NULL,
  surname varchar(35) NOT NULL,
  date_of_birth DATE NOT NULL,
  contact_number varchar(12) NOT NULL,
  FK_ADDRESS_ID int NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (PK_PERSON_ID),
  FOREIGN KEY (FK_ADDRESS_ID) REFERENCES tbl_addresses (PK_ADDRESS_ID)
);
```

and I'm trying to import data into these tables from Java using below syntaxes

```
INSERT INTO tbl_addresses (house_number,street,district,city,postcode) VALUES ('1','abc','','abc','abc');

INSERT INTO tbl_people (title,forename,surname,date_of_birth,contact_number) VALUES ('Mr','Tri ','Nguyen','1991-1-1','0123456789');
```

I got an error `Field 'FK_ADDRESS_ID'doesn't have a default value` and data actually goes into `tbl_addresses` but not `tbl_people`. Am I missing anything? Thanks in advance!

Comment: When data is inserted in `tbl_addresses ` does it have value in column `PK_ADDRESS_ID ` ?

Comment: Yes it does, just a single auto-increment integer. (e.g. 1,2,3,4,5,...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is being caused by that you labelled the `FK_ADDRESS_ID` field in the `tbl_people` table as `NOT NULL`, yet you are trying to do an `INSERT` without specifying a value for this column.

So something like this would work without error:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_people (title, forename, surname, date_of_birth,
                        contact_number, FK_ADDRESS_ID)
VALUES ('Mr', 'Tri', 'Nguyen', '1991-1-1', '0123456789', 1);
```

You could also specify a default value for `FK_ADDRESS_ID` (the error message you got alluded to this).  Here is how you could adda default value:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_people MODIFY COLUMN FK_ADDRESS_ID int NOT NULL DEFAULT 1
```

But because `FK_ADDRESS_ID` is a key into another table, the value should really be based on the primary key in `tbl_addresses`.

Comment: Thanks! How can I automatically get the ADDRESS_ID from `tbl_addresses` to `tbl_people ` btw?

Comment: SQL doesn't work this way.  Typically, you would have an application that would, for example, add an address, then add a person who is linked to that address.  Most of the time, I would expect it to be a manual process.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you are using a foreign key isn't the reason that you are getting this error. Let's take a look at your column definition.

```
FK_ADDRESS_ID int NOT NULL,
```

This is not null but does not a default. Now a look at your insert statement

```
INSERT INTO tbl_people (title,forename,surname,date_of_birth,contact_number)
```

`FK_ADDRESS_ID` isn't in your column list but it cannot be null and doesn't have a default so what can mysql do? Produce an error of course.

The best bet is to define that column as nullable.

Let's revisit the foreign key constraint.

FOREIGN KEY (FK_ADDRESS_ID) REFERENCES tbl_addresses (PK_ADDRESS_ID)

What this really says is that if you asign a value to FK_ADDRESS_ID that value should be present in PK_ADDRESS_ID column in tbl_address

as a side note, it's customary to use lower case for table/column names.